# Generating img tags with AngularJS and Docpad

Tags: angularjs, docpad

I am using DocPad for generating static content for my blog. Lately, I have been blogging on AngularJS.

I seem to be having an issue with how DocPad is generating attributes for some tags like `img`, especially for two use cases.

First, I want to demonstrate how you should use the ng-src tag and NOT the src tag in an image. I demonstrate this by showing 404 errors on page load. So I have the following HTML in my markdown file

```
    <td><img src="{{album.image}}" alt="{{album.album}} Cover Image" ></td>
```

to demonstrate this. However, during the DocPad processing it prepends the local directory to create

```
    <td><img src="/2014/01/angularjs-lou-reed/{{album.image}}" alt="{{album.album}} Cover Image" ></td>
```

When the AngularJS engine processes the page, I get 404 errors on the images.

The second issue is when I use the ng-src attribute. During processing, I am guessing, that since the src attribute of the image tag is missing it adds a src attribute into the generated HTML.

So the HTML

```
    <td><img ng-src="{{album.image}}" alt="{{album.album}} Cover Image"></td>
```

gets generated into

```
    <td><img ng-src="{{album.image}}" alt="{{album.album}} Cover Image"  src="/2014/01/angularjs-lou-reed/undefined"></td>
```

I am pretty new to DocPad and green with NodeJS. Any ideas where to look to resolve this? I think what I would like to do is if certain attributes contain AngularJS of `{{ }}` to skip the the normal processing.

You can see the generated page at

http://www.jptacek.com/2014/01/angularjs-lou-reed/

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the markdown processing and is not specific to DocPad. Which markdown plugin are you using?

Comment: Hey @ErvWalter I actually forked your GitHub repo :) I believe it is the default Markdown engine